# C# GZipStream suddenly not working

Tags: c#, string, gzip

I was using GZipStream for some time without any problems. I didn't change any code at my function but now the compress and decompress doesn't work. I have extracted the following simple example (maybe I do something wrong generally...).

```
public static class ZipLib
{
    #region Public Methods

    public static string Unzip(byte[] compressedText)
    {
        try {
            byte[] gzBuffer = compressedText;
            int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                ms.Write(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4);

                using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress, true)) {
                    zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static byte[] Zip(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) {
            zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;

        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);

        return gzBuffer;
    }

    #endregion
}

internal class Program
{
    #region Private Methods

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string uncompressedIn = "Hallo Welt";
        var compressed = ZipLib.Zip(uncompressedIn);
        var uncompressed = ZipLib.Unzip(compressed);
        Console.WriteLine("Uncompressed Input: " + uncompressedIn);
        Console.WriteLine("Compressed value: " + string.Join(" | ", compressed));
        Console.WriteLine("Uncompressed from compressed: " + string.Join(" | ", uncompressed.ToCharArray()));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The value of `uncompressed` is `"\0\0\0\0"`...

Comment: I've tried to recreate your problem using the supplied code, but I don't get any output at all: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BCSheL . Just edit that fiddle so your error is correctly recreated.

Comment: This can only work by accident.  Encoding.UTF8 cannot handle arbitrary byte values, they must be valid Unicode codepoints.  Encoding a byte[] requires Convert.To/FromeBase64String().   The Unzip() method is missing ms.Position = 0;  This has never worked before, you ought to be pretty concerned about not noticing this earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Unzip`, you `Write` to a `MemoryStream`, then give it to the `GZipStream` to read from, but: it is still at the end of the stream, you didn't rewind it. Try adding:

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

after the `Write`. Note, however, that it might be more efficient to do:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(gzBuffer, 4, gzBuffer.Length - 4))
{
     //...
}
```

this avoids duplicating any memory

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Maybe some code-cleanup actions in the past caused this problem and I was too blind to see.